# Does bitmap created as parameter need disposing?

Tags: c#

Can I simply write:

```
 using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(Image1)) {
     graph.DrawImage(Image2.Clone(Rectangle1, Image2.PixelFormat), 0, 0, Image1.Width, Image1.Height);
 }
```

Or should I write:

```
 using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(Image1))
 using (Bitmap Image3 = Image2.Clone(Rectangle1, Image2.PixelFormat)) {
     graph.DrawImage(Image3, 0, 0, Image1.Width, Image1.Height);
 }
```

Comment: You should dispose in all cases.

Comment: There just isn't much point at all in using Image2.Clone(), DrawImage() has overloads that accomplish the same and are cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

The basic rule of thumb is, if you created it and it's disposable, then you dispose it.

Comment: Sums is up nicely. Oh, and you do not ask whether it NEEDS disposing - if it is disposable, dispose it. Some may not need now, but implementation details can change.

Comment: To pile on: Microsoft says "If you are using a class that implements the IDisposable interface, you should call its Dispose implementation when you are finished using the class."https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If there's a method, which creates a disposable object and returns it to the consuming class or method. It moves the responsibility of cleaning up, to that consuming class or method. In your case - that's the clone method. The responsibility to call Dispose is moved to the class/method from your example.

In case your disposable is a field in a class - then in most cases your class should also implement `IDisposable` and dispose the field as part of it's dispose method.

This is something you should bear in mind, whenever you are working with disposable objects, and whenever you are creating disposable objects with creational patterns, such as the factory.

In some cases disposable resources are disposed by some kind of a wrapping class. For instance `StreamReader` disposes the underlying `Stream`, within its own dispose method.
Nevertheless, it still makes sense to Dispose the stream oursevles, because implementation of StreamReader, however unlikely, could change in the future.